# The Designer not recognizing Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, assembly-references

I got the following code in the designer (which was autogenerated) but it has Telerik underlined with a red color that says

> The type or namespace Telerik could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
/// <summary>
/// RadEditorCtrl control.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor RadEditorCtrl;
```

Comment: Does your reference section have a reference to Telerick.Web.UI.RadEditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check:

- In Solution Explorer, select the project.
- On the Project menu, choose Add Reference.
- The Add Reference dialog box opens.
- Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
- In the top pane, select the component you want to reference, and then click the Select button. Press CTRL while clicking to select multiple components.

Tip - If the component you are looking for is not in the list, you may locate it using the Browse button (which you will more than likely need to do)

- Click OK when you have selected all the components you need.
- Selected references will appear under the References node of the project.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this for someone who is using Telrik is use their upgrade wizard. If you chose a normal non-telerik option for your project, you can convert it and have it automatically add all required references easily.

Right click on your project and select Radcontrols for Asp.net AJAX and select Convert to Telerik Web Application.

[image]

Click Next and select the modules you'd like to include in your project. I select the following:

[image]

Click finish:

[image]

You should be able to build your project and use all the tools correctly.